# How to use rxjs ajax operator instead of axios in my react project?

Tags: ajax, reactjs, rxjs, axios, redux-observable

I am new to rxjs and want to know how to handle this use case.

This is `axios` promise, how to convert it so that it uses rxjs's ajax operator

```
export const onLogin = ({ username, password }) =>
  axios({
    method: "post",
    url: O_TOKEN_URL,
    data: querystring.stringify({
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
      grant_type: "password",
      username,
      password
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
  });
```

This is my action,

```
export const onSubmit = payload => ({
  type: FETCH_USER,
  payload // payload contains username & password
});
```

This is my epic for now,

```
export const loginEpic = action$ =>
  action$
    .ofType(FETCH_USER)
    // somehow import onLogin from above and resolve it
    // then, dispatch FETCH_USER_FULFILLED
    .do(
        payload => console.log(payload.username, payload.password)
        // i am able to console these username and password
    )
    .mapTo(() => null);
```

- I want to resolve `onLogin` function somehow, when `FETCH_USER` is dispatched, using `rxjs's ajax operator`.
- And, I want `onLogin` function, which returns `promise/observable`, to be set up in different file so that I can keep track of all the ajax requests

These are the packages,

```
"redux-observable": "^0.18.0",
"rxjs": "^5.5.10",
```

- Could you also point me to a documentation that covers this and various use case for `post`, `put` ... requests? I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ajax config object is fairly similar to what you already have. I'm assuming the data property for the axios request is the request body.

```
import {ajax} from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax';

export const onLogin = ({ username, password }) =>
  ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: O_TOKEN_URL,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      client_secret: CLIENT_SECRET,
      grant_type: "password",
      username,
      password
    }),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
  });
```

Your epic would look something like this:

```
export const loginEpic = action$ =>
  action$
    .ofType(FETCH_USER)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      onLogin(action.payload)
        // map will be called when the request succeeded
        //   so we dispatch the success action here.
        .map((ajaxResponse) => fetchUserFulfilled())
        // catch will be called if the request failed
        //   so we dispatch the error action here.
        // Note that you must return an observable from this function.
        // For more advanced cases, you can also apply retry logic here. 
        .catch((ajaxError, source$) => Observable.of(fetchUserFailed()))
    );
```

Where `fetchUserFulfilled` and `fetchUserFailed` are action creator functions.

There does not seem to be much documentation of the RxJS 5 ajax method yet. Here are the links to the official v5 docs for the [AjaxRequest](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/observable/dom/MiscJSDoc.js~AjaxRequestDoc.html), [AjaxResponse](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.js~AjaxResponse.html) and [AjaxError](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.js~AjaxError.html). The AjaxError object in particular has 0 information so far (at the time of this answer) so you will need to rely on the source code if you need to use this object for more than a trigger to tell the user that something went wrong. The ajax source code is [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/observable/dom/AjaxObservable.ts).